# Transfering data from a WPF application to a word document

Tags: wpf, ms-word, transfer

What I'm looking for is a point in the right direction.  I'm teaching myself Visual Studios 2010.  I have a WPF application with text boxes.  What I'd like to do is transfer that data to a word document and then print it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code from [this link](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/creating-word-document-using-c/) should help, it will allow you to create a word document with the text "Hello World" and save it to "D:\MyWord.doc"

```
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object Visible=true;
        object start1 = 0;
        object end1 = 0;

        ApplicationClass WordApp = new ApplicationClass();
        Document adoc = WordApp.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
        Range rng = adoc.Range(ref start1, ref missing);

        try
        {              
            rng.Font.Name = “Georgia”;
            rng.InsertAfter(“Hello World!”);
            object filename = @”D:\MyWord.doc”;
            adoc.SaveAs(ref filename, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
            ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
            WordApp.Visible = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```